# How to migrate API from ExpressJS to NestJS?

Tags: express, nestjs

How to migrate API from ExpressJS to NestJS?

What should I do for the first step?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear in your question?

Comment: There is no other way than writing your code in Nestjs format, but it totally worth it, good luck with.